# How can I write a concise code in c#?

Tags: c#

How can I write a concise code in c#?  I am sure this will lead to become a great programmer.
Is thr any book that I can follow that teaches on writing neat and clean c# code?

Comment: There are plenty of, "What's a good C# book?" questions and answers on stackoverflow. Do a search.

Comment: Do you know c#? I think a lot of writing clean and concise code is knowing the language well. Otherwise you'll reinvest things that are built into the framework, or do things sub-optimally, simply out of not knowing any better

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477748/what-are-the-best-c-net-books

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189225/c-books-for-developers-that-know-object-oriented-programming

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048/what-is-the-best-book-to-learn-c

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the comments or the closing reason, the question is pretty clear (even if not grammatically correct, but this is not english.stackexchange.com). He wants to become a better programmer and he is asking for suggestions of good books to do so.

Comment: I searched for questions relating to my question but couldn't find any nor any suggestions matched my requirements ...so i posted a new one...can you please open it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) by Uncle Bob. Great easy read. I consider it a must for any programmer in any language. It's not specific to C# but that's not really that important considering what the book can lead you to.

There are many others but I would start there. To complement, [The Art of Unit Testing](http://artofunittesting.com/) is a nice read as well and can get you far fast.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks ale..i will get Clean Code and see if it makes me any better....i guess thr is no book that says "Road to become greatest c# programmmer ever"...lol